# MySQL Error: JSON documents may not contain NULL member names when sorting by 'created_at' in query with JSON_OBJECTAGG

Tags: mysql

In my database, I run this query:

```sql
SELECT blueprints.*, JSON_OBJECTAGG(properties.ui_reference_name, blueprint_values.value) AS json_properties
FROM `blueprints`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `blueprint_values` ON `blueprint_values`.`blueprint_id` = `blueprints`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `properties` ON `properties`.`id` = `blueprint_values`.`property_id`
WHERE `blueprints`.`game_id` = 1
GROUP BY blueprints.id
ORDER BY `blueprints`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

I'm getting a MySQL error: "JSON documents may not contain NULL member names."

The explain of the query is:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type   | possible_keys                          | key                                    | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blueprints       | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,index_blueprints_on_slug       | index_blueprints_on_game_id            | 8       | const                                   | 92108 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blueprint_values | NULL       | ref    | index_blueprint_values_on_blueprint_id | index_blueprint_values_on_blueprint_id | 8       | cardtrader.blueprints.id                |     8 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | properties       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY                                | 8       | cardtrader.blueprint_values.property_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

However, if I modify the query to sort by ID instead of created_at, the query works, and the explain changes as follows:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type   | possible_keys                          | key                                    | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blueprints       | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,index_blueprints_on_slug       | index_blueprints_on_game_id            | 8       | const                                   | 92108 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blueprint_values | NULL       | ref    | index_blueprint_values_on_blueprint_id | index_blueprint_values_on_blueprint_id | 8       | cardtrader.blueprints.id                |     8 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | properties       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY                                | 8       | cardtrader.blueprint_values.property_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL           |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
```

The only things that change are "Using temporary; Using filesort" in the first query vs "Using filesort" in the last one.

Can someone explain why this happens? How can I fix the query while maintaining the sorting by created_at?

I don't know if you need more info, but in case I can add it in the comments.

Comment: Can you clarify why you used `OUTER JOIN` if you don't want NULLs?

Comment: Because I don’t want exclude blueprints. I want also null. But the problem is why if I order by created_at the query does not work and if I order by id works.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug. If you can create a minimal test case, I would recommend reporting it at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: My question was related to the fact that your `properties` table is on the side of the outer join that will return NULLs if there is no match. But you're using `properties.ui_reference_name` as the keys in your JSON object, so in cases where the blueprint has no properties, you'll be using NULL as the JSON object key, which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `properties.ui_reference_name` in the first row is NULL if you order by created_at. Try to verify output without building JSON.

Comment: I've verified. The record is the same if I order by id or created_at and the key is not null.